# Why field injection causes class is difficult to test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, guice, mockito

According [Google I/O 2009 - Big Modular Java with Guice (at 29:55)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBVJbzAagfs) using field injection makes testing harder than constructor or setter injection.

Let's consider NewsService class:

```
public class NewsService{

    @Inject Storage storage;
    @Inject Authenticator auth;

    public void addNews(String data){
       if(auth.authenticate()){
          storage.save(data);
       }
    }
}
```

and unit test for NewsService:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class NewsServiceTest{

    @Mock Storage storage;
    @Mock Authenticator auth;
    @InjectMocks NewsService sut; //system under test

    @Test
    public void addNews_ShouldCallSaveOnStorage_WhenAuthIsSucceed(){
       when(auth.authenticate()).thenReturn(true);
       sut.addNews("mocked data");
       verify(storage).save("mocked data");
    }
}
```

Mockito can inject mocks even to private fields. Taking care about encapsulation is important, so I use package visibility. 
Even if Storage and Authenticator classes are in different package than NewsService and both still use package visibility for their own fields, I don't care about it, because NewsService don't have to access any field from Storage or Authenticator, because I mocked their behaoviour.
Even if I would change NewsService to use constructor injection, my unit test class wouldn't change.
So the question is: does field injection really causes testing harder with keeping well-designed architecture?

Comment: See http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/ for a nice explaination why it is evil.

Comment: This is not related to testing but another big drawback of field injection is that your object is not immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Field injection is more difficult because there's necessarily reflection involved; for example, if you were testing a class with constructor injection, you'd just create mock dependencies and pass them to `new`. Writing directly to private fields requires a good bit of bookkeeping.

Note, however, that that talk is more than four years old. As you demonstrate, tools for dependency injection (both for testing and production) have come a long way since then, and `@Inject` is the official Java standard now. You can use a test framework to handle all of the reflection for you and easily test objects with injected dependencies.

Comment: So when the reflection nowadays is common way to mocking and remembering it allows to write less code I can say: field injection is not bad (maybe good) approach?

Comment: @mate Field injection does have some downsides, and I do recommend reading the article, but difficulty in wiring up unit tests is no longer one of them.